# Non-Retina (non-IPS) Display on Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display

I experience bad headaches and dizziness from Retina (IPS) Displays. All new Mac laptops have Retinas.  I am currently using a 2012 Macbook Air (non-retina).

Are there any *new Mac laptop that can run Big Sur (OSX 11) or later that is also non-Retina?

If not, is it possible to buy any version of a
Mac laptop and replace the screen with a non-Retina to get Big Sur or later with a non-Retina.

I need to a laptop to work remotely in different locations so buying an external display won't work.

Comment: Are you sure that "Retina" is the cause of your headaches? Not the display rate, or the lighting? How much testing have you done to see what brings them on? I would also discuss this with your doctor, if you haven't, as this could be a symptom of some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt very much that there is any "other" display that you can fit into a Mac laptop.

The last non-Retina Mac laptop was the MacBook Air 2017, which will run OSes between 10.12.4 (Sierra) and macOS 12 (Monterey).